# Slice operator for iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator, slice

I'm looking for a way to slice an iterator, I couldn't find a proper way to do it using an existing standard method/function.

Here is what I want to do:

```js
// Suppose I have this generator:
function* range(n){
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1){
    yield i;
  }
}

// This is obviously not desirable as we create a large array:
console.log(Array.from(range(100)).slice(2, 5));
// -> [ 2, 3, 4 ]

// What I'm looking for is an existing function that would be equivalent to this: 
function* islice(iterable, start, end){
  if (!end){
    end = start;
    start = 0;
  }
  dropfirsts(iterable, start);
  yield* firsts(iterable, end-start);
}

function dropfirsts(iterable, n){
  for (let i of range(n)){ 
    if (iterable.next().done) return;
  }
}

function* firsts(iterable, n){
  for (let j of range(n)){
    const item = iterable.next();
    if (item.done) return;
    yield item.value;
  }
}

console.log(Array.from(islice(range(10), 2, 5)));
// -> [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Note that I'm not looking for a complete implementation of an `islice` function, instead I'm looking for a equivalent to this inside the standard library.

Comment: This seems unherently difficult, because iterators don't have indexes. Each time you call `islice()`, the current state will reset to `0`.

Comment: There is (unfortunately) no standard library for working with iterators / generators.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a bit strange to have iterators without a way to work with them. Is there a commonly accepted third party solution to this lack of iterator tools?